# exam exercise on Series problem.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

The exercise states: Does the series 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \int_{0}^1 \frac{x^n dx}{x+1}$$  converge?

The solution states as the first step: $$I_n =\int_{0}^1 \frac{x^n dx}{x+1} $$ then $ \frac{1}{2(n+1)}\le I_n \le \frac{1}{n+1} $

This is not really self evident to me, could someone explain where this inequality comes from to me?

Comment: Hint. How big or small can $x + 1$ be on the interval $[0,1]$? Use your answer to find functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f(x) \leq x^n/(x+1) \leq g(x)$, but which are simpler to integrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac{x^n}{0+1} \geq\dfrac{x^n}{x+1} \geq \dfrac{x^n}{1+1}$